# Should I create 3 fields or create one 1-to-many relationship?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design

I have a table called query where medical data such as medicine are stored, in the form I have up to 3 fields of medicines. In the table I must create these 3 fields or I create another table called medicines and I make a one-to-many relationship from the query table to the medicine table

I have not yet created the tables, so I doubt that it is better.

these medicine data can be null, that is to say, in the form they can leave those medicine input blank or fill in 1

Comment: Question is asked as per thaught. No problem occur in it

Comment: Today, there are 3 fields.  Tomorrow, the boss will say there must be 4.  So, do not use 3 columns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose the solution with three columns:

- If you need to search for a specific medicine, to see who is using it, which column would you search? Could it be in any of the three? Does that make your search query more complex? (*yes*) Can it be indexed? (*no*)
- Why did you pick three columns? What if some patient is using four or five medications? How will you know how many columns is enough? If you add more columns, does this make all your existing search queries even more complex? (*yes, it does*)
- If a certain patient is using three medications, but stops taking the medication in the first column, do you need to move the other two over to the left-most columns? Why?

**All these difficult questions go away if you use a second table in a one-to-many relationship.**

Comment: Thank you very much I feel that you took the blindfold off my eyes, now I see everything more clearly.